# How to sort a list and return the value in Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I have a use case for which I have to automate the following steps:

1. Create an empty list
2. Push data into the empty list
3. Keep/save the original order in a variable
4. Sort the original order
5. Save the sorted list
6. Reverse the sorted list and return value

   ```
   *** Settings ***
   Library  SeleniumLibrary
   Library  Collections

   *** Keywords ***
   Sort order verification
       @{username_list}=   Create List                        //creates an empty list
       @{get_name}=   Get WebElements     css=#userTable > tbody > tr> td:nth-child(1)
       :FOR    ${each}     IN      @{get_name}
       \  ${get_username}=  Get Text    ${each}
       \  Append To List  ${username_list}  ${get_username}   //pushes data into list in iteration
       ${original_order}=  Copy list  ${username_list}        //returns original order
       ${sorted_list}=  Sort List  ${original_order}          //sorts the list but returns none(nothing is saved in the variable
       ${reverse_sorted_list}=  Reverse List  ${sorted_list}  //returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reverse'
   ```

Comment: Can you explain what it is that this code isn't doing for you as you had intended it? Right now you're leaving us guessing as to what does work, and what doesn't.

Comment: @poovin Are you asking Question?

Comment: @A.Kootstra I have edited the code indicating what works and what doesn't

Comment: Just going to ask for the obvious here, but are you sure that there is an actual list-of-values in the original variable `${username_list}`?

Comment: @A.Kootstra Yes, There is an actual list of values in the original variable ${username_list}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Sort List` and `Reverse List` keywords modify the list in-place, e.g. they change the value of the target variable.

They also don't return anything - thus on the lines you've used them, you have assigned the value `None` to the variables, which led to the error.

You can read about this behavior in the [Collections library documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html)

Comment: Is there any other way to return values from Sort List and Reverse List

Comment: As it's in-place, pretty much no other way but what you do - copy in another variable, and sort/reverse it.